# PULL DATA FROM TWO SHEETS

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Looking for an excel formula to match data in sheet 1 column A (delivery number) to data in sheet 2 column B (delivery number), then pull the data that's in sheet 2 column A (PO number) to a new column in sheet 1.  There are more lines in Sheet 2 column B than in Sheet 1, column A.  Please help!

Comment: What have you tried?  You should look at the [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) which will tell you more about how to ask a good question.

Comment: WOW! Ok...I'm not familiar with formulas, Theresa, so i think my question IS a good question.

Comment: Hi pnuts.  There are more lines in Sheet 2 column B than in Sheet 1 column A because Sheet 2 column B has all Delivery numbers.  I'm trying to take the PO numbers from Sheet 2 and add them to a different column in sheet 1, but I need to match the delivery numbers first.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If the PO number is numeric you can use =SUMIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,A2)/COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!A2)

Comment: Thanks Andrey.  My PO Number is alpha numeric.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible. Add column C in Sheet2 that duplicates column A and use VLOOKUP

Comment: Thanks Andrey.  Could you give me a VLOOKUP formula after adding column C that duplicates column A?  As I stated, I'm not familiar with formulas.  Thanks again!